# Send to AJAX name and value of selected option

Tags: jquery, ajax, select

I am trying to send through ajax the name and the value of a selected option in a dropdown menu so as to be able to launch a sql-request including the selected option.

Here is what I have so far:

jQuery:

```
$('#form_stadt_kanton').select(function() {
    var kanton = $('#form_stadt_kanton').find(":selected");
    $.ajax({
                // Daten sammeln
                url: "wholephp.php",  // Selbe Domain
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "text",
                data: kanton,
                success: function(para) {
                    $("#allecheckboxes").html(para)
                    drawMarkersMap()
                } // Ende Function
            }) // Ende ajax
            ereignis.preventDefault(); //Stop der Formular-Aktion
}) //Ende function
```

and html/php:

```
<form method="GET" action="" id="form_stadt_kanton">
        <table>
            <tr><th><label for="stadt">Nach <b>Stadt</b> filtern:</label></th></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="text" id="stadteingabe" value="Stadt eingeben">
```

```
        <table class="tablefloatright">
            <tr><th><label for="kanton">Nach <b>Kanton</b> filtern:</label></th></tr>
            <tr><td><select><option id="">Kanton auswählen</option>
            <?php
            $i = 1;
            foreach ($kantone as $kanton) {
                echo "<option name='kanton".$i."' value='".$kanton."'>".$kanton."</option>";
                $i=$i+1;
            } 
            ?>
            </select></td></tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

In the php-file "wholephp.php", I would like to be able to use the following code: `foreach($_GET as $name => $wert)`
That's why I need to get the name of the option along with its value. Depending on what the "name" is, the WHERE condition is different.

I would greatly appreciate any help in this matter. It can't be too complicated, but I just don't get it. Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I could finally solve the problem with serializeArray(). Here is what the (working) code looks like:

jQuery / Ajax:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function(){
    //var kanton = $('#form_stadt_kanton').find(":selected");
    var kanton = $('#form_stadt_kanton').serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
                // Daten sammeln
                url: "wholephp.php",  // Selbe Domain
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "text",
                data: kanton,
                success: function(para) {
                    $("#allecheckboxes").html(para)
                    drawMarkersMap()
                } // Ende Function
            }) // Ende ajax
            ereignis.preventDefault(); //Stop der Formular-Aktion
}) //Ende function
```

HTML / PHP:

```
<form method="GET" action="" id="form_stadt_kanton">
        <table>
            <tr><th><label for="kanton">Nach <b>Kanton</b> filtern:</label></th></tr>
            <tr><td><select name='kanton'><option value="" selected='selected'>Kanton auswählen</option>
            <?php
            $i = 1;
            foreach ($kantone as $kanton) {
                echo "<option value='".$kanton."'>".$kanton."</option>";
                $i=$i+1;
            } 
            ?>
            </select></td></tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var kanton = $('#sel_kanton').val();
```

Add `id='sel_kanton'` to your `select element` like,

```
<select id='sel_kanton'>...
```

Pass it in `ajax data` like,

```
data: {kanton:kanton},
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Unfortunately, it does not seem to work, but maybe I have misunderstood you: I have to add the same id to the form and to the select element, or two different ones? You used id "sel_kanton": is that a "replacement" of id "form_stat_kanton" or is it an additional id for the select element?

Comment: No, don't change `form-id` add `id` to your `select element` only. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. It still does not work though. I must have made a mistake somewhere else in the code. Thank you for your help anyway, I really appreciate it! :-)